# Игра "сапер". Как окружающим бомбу 8 ячейкам добавить единицу в массиве?

Tags: javascript

```
   for(var i=0;i<+document.getElementById("rows").value;i++)
{
    for(var j=0;j<+document.getElementById("columns").value;j++)
        if(field[i][j]=='x')
        {
                for (var upLine = j - 1; upLine < j + 1; upLine++)
                    try {
                        if (field[i - 1][upLine] != "x")
                            field[i - 1][upLine]++;
                    }
                    catch (error){}

                    for (var downLine = j - 1; downLine < j + 1; downLine++)
                        try {
                            if (field[i + 1][downLine] != "x")
                                field[i + 1][downLine]++;
                        }
                        catch (error){}

                try {
                    if (field[i][j - 1] != 'x')
                        field[i][j - 1]++;
                }
                catch (error){}
                try {
                    if (field[i][j + 1] != 'x')
                        field[i][j + 1]++;
                }
                catch (error){}
        }

}
```

У меня есть массив, который я сначала заполняю "бомбами" а потом уже заполняю цифрами. Такой код явно плохой а ещё и не рабочий.

Comment: try-catch выпиливай.

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда будет выход за пределы массива.

Comment: Ну так надо чтоб не было...

Comment: ... который исправляется с помощью `try/catch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function fillMatrix() {
  var rows = +document.getElementById("rows").value;
  var cols = +document.getElementById("columns").value;

  // create matrix, randomly put mines in ~20% of cells
  var field = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    field[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      field[i][j] = 0;
      if (Math.random() < 0.2)
        field[i][j] = "x";
    }
  }

  // count mines in adjacent cells
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

      if (field[i][j] != "x")
        continue;

      for (var i1 = Math.max(0, i - 1); i1 <= Math.min(i + 1, rows - 1); i1++) {
        for (var j1 = Math.max(0, j - 1); j1 <= Math.min(j + 1, cols - 1); j1++) {
          if (field[i1][j1] != "x")
            field[i1][j1] = field[i1][j1] + 1;
        }
      }

    }
  }

  // visualize      
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(field[i].join(" ")));
}
```

```html
Rows:<input id="rows" value="5"/>
Columns:<input id="columns" value="5"/>
<button onclick="fillMatrix()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Странно. Почему-то не везде срабатывает.

Comment: https://ibb.co/g6NAax вот скриншот.

Comment: @AshenOne Мы с Вами в неравном положении. Вы видите весь мой код - и он работает правильно. Я не вижу Вашего кода - и должен угадать по Вашей картинке, почему он работает неправильно. Вы, очевидно, неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: Всё что Вы написали, похожее с моим. Генерация рандомных мин на поле,генерация чисел возле мин и генерация таблицы.

Comment: @AshenOne В программировании "похожее" и "такое же" - две большие разницы.

Comment: куда кидать код?

Comment: @AshenOne - в вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73457/discussion-between-ashen-one-and-igor).